# How to get the total sum

Tags: java, sum

I have this code to school assignment, it works with no errors but it won't "sum" the number it's just show them together!
for example it shows like this:

Total:
2
3

and it suppose to be:
Total:
5

```
enter code here
public void getTotalPower()
{
   for (BigGun oneGun : gun)
   {
       System.out.println(oneGun.getNumberPower());
   }
}
```

Comment: Use an *accumulator*: an `int` you initialize with `0` and add the `oneGun.getNumberPower()` to that variable in each iteration.

Comment: Bonus points for someone who can do this using streams :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a variable which stores the sum of the power. You just have to add the value of the current gun to it in the loop:

```
   public void getTotalPower()
    {
       int totalPower = 0;
       for (BigGun oneGun : gun)
       {
           totalPower += oneGun.getNumberPower();
       }
       System.out.println(totalPower);
    }
```

Comment: just 1 Q. : what does (int totalPower = 0) mean?

Comment: It will not work because gun list is not being passed

Comment: please pass arraylist gun as parameter to the method/function

Comment: @Inger: it means that you initialize a variable that stores the value. The starting value is 0. It is just to store the total Power. Then you add the value of each gun to it, so that you get the sum ;)

Comment: @128 ever thought about the possibility that the gun list is a member variable?

Answer (score 1):

if youre using java 8 you can use streams

```
public void getTotalPower(){

    int totalPower = gun.stream()
                        .mapToInt(BigGun::getNumberPower)
                        .sum();
    System.out.println(totalPower);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please parse string to integer using wrapper class and return the Integer value Integer.parseInt(StringValue)
i.e

```
public Integer getTotalPower(ArrayList<BigGun> gun)
{
   int sum=0;
   for (BigGun oneGun : gun)
   {
        sum=sum+Integer.parseInt(oneGun.getNumberPower());
       System.out.println(oneGun.getNumberPower());
   }
return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add them together?

```
public void getTotalPower()
{
int sum=0;
   for (BigGun oneGun : gun)
   {
       sum+=oneGun.getNumberPower();
   }
  System.out.println(sum);
}
```